# API response slow

Tags: performance, api, response

My script works overall, but the API response is really slow.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$config = include('config.php');
$predictions = include('predicton.php');

function fetchData($currency) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'.$currency.'/?convert=EUR'
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}

function convertData($currency) {

    global $config;

    $response = fetchData($currency);

    $id = $response[0]['id'];
    $name = $response[0]['name'];
    $value = $response[0]['price_eur'];
    $perc_change_h = $response[0]['percent_change_1h'];
    $perc_change_d = $response[0]['percent_change_24h'];
    $perc_change_w = $response[0]['percent_change_7d'];


    $amount = $config[$currency]['amount'];
    $starting_price = $config[$currency]['starting_price'];


    $spend = $amount * $starting_price;
    $total = $amount * $value;

    $profit = $total - $spend;

    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'value' => round($value, 4),
        'change_hour' => $perc_change_h,
        'change_day' => $perc_change_d,
        'change_week' => $perc_change_w,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'starting' => number_format($starting_price, 4),
        'spend' => number_format($spend, 2),
        'total' => number_format($total, 2),
        'profit' => number_format($profit, 2)
    );
}

function convertPrediction ($currency, $percentage) {
    global $config, $predictions;

    $amount = $config[$currency]['amount'];
    $prediction = $predictions[$currency]['value'];

    $value = $amount * $prediction / 100 * $percentage;
    $value = round($value, 2);

    return $value;
}
```

This is the site: http://bitcap.kazuto.de/

A sample api request: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/stellar/?convert=EUR

The response itself is quick, but not when running in my code. It takes around 11-13 seconds to refresh, even though not much data is requested at all.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You may want to try a process of elimination. You say the return is fast, so start commenting out code and do a print after each function call to determine which function is the cause.

Comment: I've commented the main section out and it runs smooth. So it has to do something with this: https://pastebin.com/ypmCzfbD

Comment: It seems like my script doesn't just send one request per $currency but multiple requests, apparently 20 per $currency, so currently 80 in total.

Comment: Problem probably is where you are making so many requests and it is just stacking up as each call has to go through all your functions. Try to reduce the call to just a single and then process the response a single time or make all your calls and put each response in a single global variable (array type or similar) and after all calls are complete, process the global a single time through your functions.

Comment: Nothing I'm trying to do works D: xD

Comment: Got it work. I've converted the response to an object and call the function once for each $currency as $response inside the foreach loop. This way I can access the data with `$response->price_eur` and so on.